# Tomcat - cookie with ':' in the cookie value

Tags: tomcat, cookies, websphere, tomcat7, setcookie

We recently migrated our application from Websphere to tomcat-7. and we are running into a compatibility issue with the way cookies are handled in tomcat.

The cookie value we send to the client browser will have the character : in it. In tomcat 7 the presence of this : character is causing the cookie value to be set enclosed within double quotes in the client browser. Whereas in WAS it does not enclose the cookie value within quotes.

Ex: 
For a cookie with key->Key and value->val1:val2:val3

In Tomcat 7,
Set-Cookie  Key="val1:val2:val3";

In WAS,
Set-Cookie  Key=val1:val2:val3;

Has any one seen this behavior? Is there a tomcat setting to escape the quotes?

Your suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of system properties that might help:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html

You'll need to test carefully as changing the strictness can impact other parts of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Colon (:) is an invalid character value in cookies. RFC 6265 suggest that you encode your cookie values in order to avoid compatibility issues with illegal characters.